# Incompatible spring boot version causing application to not start up. How can we identify the wrong version included in the pom

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, apache-camel

I have the following pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.cnt.orchtn</groupId>
        <artifactId>orchtn-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../orchtn-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>

    </parent>

    <groupId>com.dsfsdaf.orchtn</groupId>
    <artifactId>orchen-con-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-RELEASE</version>
    <name>OrchServi</name>
    <description>Orch</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <camel.version>3.1.0</camel.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
        <kafka.version>2.6.0</kafka.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-kafka-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
             <!--  <version>2.10.0</version> -->
             <version>2.11.3</version> 
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20200518</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <!-- This dependency is for WebClient implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolt-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</id>
            <name>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</name>
            <url>https://cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory-255474220078.d.codeartifact.us-east 
                        1.amazonaws.com/maven/cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Maven-Artifactory-Plugin</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</id>
            <name>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</name>
            <url>https://cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory-255474220078.d.codeartifact.us-east
                 1.amazonaws.com/maven/cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
                </plugin> -->
                
                
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


I have the parent pom in the following format:

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cnt.orctr</groupId>
    <artifactId>orctr-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Orch Parent</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>




        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>5.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.11</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</id>
            <name>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</name>
            <url>https://cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory-255474220078.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Maven-Artifactory-Plugin</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <distributionManagement>

        <repository>

            <id>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</id>

            <name>cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory--cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory</name>

            <url>https://cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory-255474220078.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory/</url>

        </repository>

    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-info</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>publish</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactory>
                                    <includeEnvVars>true</includeEnvVars>
                                    <envVarsExcludePatterns>*password*,*secret*,*key*,*token*,*passphrase*</envVarsExcludePatterns>
                                    <timeoutSec>60</timeoutSec>
                                </artifactory>
                                <publisher>
                                    <contextUrl>https://cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory-255474220078.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/cnc-clng-srd-cbf-artifactory/</contextUrl>
                                    <username>aws</username>
                                    <password>${env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}</password>
                                    <repoKey>libs-release-local</repoKey>
                                    <snapshotRepoKey>libs-snapshot-local</snapshotRepoKey>
                                </publisher>
                                <!-- <buildInfo> <buildName>centene-framework</buildName> <buildNumber>${buildnumber}</buildNumber> 
                                    <buildUrl>http://build-url.org</buildUrl> </buildInfo> -->
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run the application I get the following:

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.startup.StartupEndpointAutoConfiguration$ApplicationStartupCondition.getMatchOutcome(StartupEndpointAutoConfiguration.java:63)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.getApplicationStartup()Lorg/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup;
```

The method's class, org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/cn249124/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users/cn249124/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: I am sure my dependent versions in the parent are conflicting with the child pom. Spring-boot-starter 3.1.0.  Where do I find what version  and dependent pom's I am supposed to include in my child pom and what dependencies to include in parent

Comment: What I mean is the versions in the parent pom seems to be creating a problem with spring-boot-starter-3.1.0 any site I can validate against what versions are compatible and what need to be present in the parent pom and what need not be.  Also I tried the bom dependency through dependencyManagement .  That was also creating a problem

Comment: start.spring.io - here you can create spring projects and choose which SB version you want, and it picks the compatible Camel version. Also you are using an old EOL version of Camel with v3.1

Comment: You are mixing different spring boot versions .... cleanup your pom file and use only a single version...

Answer (score 1):

See this page for using Camel Spring Boot:
https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/

Here you can use camel-spring-boot-bom that picks all the compatible versions for you. That is also what the camel spring boot examples shows:
https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples